# Kafka Connect breaks Microservices Strategy

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-kafka-connect

My understanding of microservices is that a service should have exclusive access to a particular database.  In other words, services should not share databases.

Now suppose one wants to use Kafka Connect to save the data within Kafka into persistent storage such as MySQL.  If I were to create a rest api to fetch that data from the persistent storage, would it then not be a microservice?

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-dichotomy-rethinking-the-way-we-treat-data-and-services/

Comment: Thank you Matthias!  So there will always to be tradeoffs.  So it is best when using Kafka connect, to save the data into a database that is read only.  This is what I am taking from the "centralize an immutable streams of facts"

Comment: I don't understand the question. So you have a microservice that needs to persist some data into a database. You create  inside that microservice a REST endpoint so others (other microservices) access that data the your microservice will not be considered a microservice anymore or what?

Comment: Microservices usually are distributed solution for old fashion Monolit + SQL. The problem is that someone need to implement the WAL / Trx logs. Kafka + kafka connect is a great solution for that part.